# Multiple midi pin support for a midi driver in XP

Tags: c++, windows, device-driver, midi

I am trying to create a miniport driver (IMiniportDMus) that will expose two midi in and two midi out pins (legacy). In Windows Vista and Win 7 I see those pins when I use midiInXXX and midiOutXXX functions, but in Windows XP I just see one midi in and one midi out pin.

Here is my pin descriptor array:

```
static PCPIN_DESCRIPTOR MiniportPins[] =
{
    {
    kMaxNumLegacyRenderStreams, kMaxNumLegacyRenderStreams, 0,  // InstanceCount
    NULL,                                                       // AutomationTable
    {                                                           // KsPinDescriptor
        0,                                                      // InterfacesCount
        NULL,                                                   // Interfaces
        0,                                                      // MediumsCount
        NULL,                                                   // Mediums
        SIZEOF_ARRAY(PinDataRangePointersStreamLegacy),         // DataRangesCount
        PinDataRangePointersStreamLegacy,                       // DataRanges
        KSPIN_DATAFLOW_IN,                                      // DataFlow
        KSPIN_COMMUNICATION_SINK,                               // Communication
        (GUID *) &KSCATEGORY_AUDIO,                             // Category
        &KSAUDFNAME_MIDI,                                       // Name
        0                                                       // Reserved
    }
},
{
    kMaxNumCaptureStreams, kMaxNumCaptureStreams, 0,            // InstanceCount
    NULL,                                                       // AutomationTable
    {                                                           // KsPinDescriptor
        0,                                                      // InterfacesCount
        NULL,                                                   // Interfaces
        0,                                                      // MediumsCount
        NULL,                                                   // Mediums
        SIZEOF_ARRAY(PinDataRangePointersStreamLegacy),         // DataRangesCount
        PinDataRangePointersStreamLegacy,                       // DataRanges
        KSPIN_DATAFLOW_OUT,                                     // DataFlow
        KSPIN_COMMUNICATION_SINK,                               // Communication
        (GUID *) &KSCATEGORY_AUDIO,                             // Category
        &KSAUDFNAME_MIDI,                                       // Name
        0                                                       // Reserved
    }
},
{
    kMaxNumLegacyRenderStreams, kMaxNumLegacyRenderStreams, 0,  // InstanceCount
    NULL,                                                       // AutomationTable
    {                                                           // KsPinDescriptor
        0,                                                      // InterfacesCount
        NULL,                                                   // Interfaces
        0,                                                      // MediumsCount
        NULL,                                                   // Mediums
        SIZEOF_ARRAY(PinDataRangePointersStreamLegacy),         // DataRangesCount
        PinDataRangePointersStreamLegacy,                       // DataRanges
        KSPIN_DATAFLOW_IN,                                      // DataFlow
        KSPIN_COMMUNICATION_SINK,                               // Communication
        (GUID *) &KSCATEGORY_AUDIO,                             // Category
        &KSAUDFNAME_MIDI,                                       // Name
        0                                                       // Reserved
    }
},
{
    kMaxNumCaptureStreams, kMaxNumCaptureStreams, 0,            // InstanceCount
    NULL,                                                       // AutomationTable
    {                                                           // KsPinDescriptor
        0,                                                      // InterfacesCount
        NULL,                                                   // Interfaces
        0,                                                      // MediumsCount
        NULL,                                                   // Mediums
        SIZEOF_ARRAY(PinDataRangePointersStreamLegacy),         // DataRangesCount
        PinDataRangePointersStreamLegacy,                       // DataRanges
        KSPIN_DATAFLOW_OUT,                                     // DataFlow
        KSPIN_COMMUNICATION_SINK,                               // Communication
        (GUID *) &KSCATEGORY_AUDIO,                             // Category
        &KSAUDFNAME_MIDI,                                       // Name
        0                                                       // Reserved
    }
}
};
```

I could not find any information if Windows XP supports multiple midi pins. I even updated the pin names by defining specific GUIDs and registering those.

Is this a known issue or am I doing something wrong?